# Go (redirect) to a page with custom headers?

Tags: php, header

I need to go to a page which is forbidden without a custom header:

```
x: something
```

Is this possible? I don't want to get the content of the page (curl or file_get_contents()), I want to redirect there with a header set.

Comment: Do you want the client's browser to send the header? If so, then it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks @ajshort! Write this as answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can redirect the header like this.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

You can not output any html to the page before you use this. If you output any html the headers are automatically sent out before the output. (unless you have output buffering turned on). You can read more about this here.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Also, if by forbidden you mean 403 Forbidden then you probably have incorrect file permissions set or certain apache configurations set.

Comment: This does not answer the question - I think they want the client's browser to send the custom header.